# Vue Language dropdown show current language

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component named: DropdownLanguage.vue

Objective: I want to display the current active language by default at `:text="selectedOptionDropdown"`. Like `languages.name` (e.g. English). I'm stuck how to manage this.

```
<template>
  <b-dropdown id="dropdown-buttons" :text="selectedOptionDropdown" class="m-2">
      <template v-for="(item, i) in languages">
        <b-dropdown-item-button class="eslanguage" v-bind:data-lang="item.lang" :key="i" @click="selectedLanguage">{{ item.name }}</b-dropdown-item-button>
    </template>
  </b-dropdown>
</template>

<script>
import i18nService from "@/core/services/i18n.service.js";

export default {
  name: "ESDropdownLanguage",
  data() {
    return {
      languages: i18nService.languages,
      selectedOptionDropdown: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    selectedLanguage(e) {
        const el = e.target.closest("eslanguage");
        const lang = el.getAttribute("data-lang");

        i18nService.setActiveLanguage(lang);
    },
    selectedOptionDropdown() {
     // No idea what to do
    }
  },
  computed: {
  }
};
</script>
```

Other file:

```
const i18nService = {
  defaultLanguage: "en",

  languages: [
    {
      lang: "en",
      name: "English",
      flag: process.env.BASE_URL + "media/svg/flags/226-united-states.svg"
    },
    {
      lang: "nl",
      name: "Nederlands",
      flag: process.env.BASE_URL + "media/svg/flags/237-netherlands.svg"
    }
  ],

  /**
   * Keep the active language in the localStorage
   * @param lang
   */
  setActiveLanguage(lang) {
    localStorage.setItem("language", lang);
  },

  /**
   * Get the current active language
   * @returns {string | string}
   */
  getActiveLanguage() {
    return localStorage.getItem("language") || this.defaultLanguage;
  }
};

export default i18nService;
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Your question is a bit vague as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Add v-model to the dropdown, and use computed properties.

Here is a working example: [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
<template>
  <select v-model="language">
      <option :value="item.lang" v-for="(item, i) in languages">
        {{ item.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    languages() {
      return i18nService.languages
    },
    language: {
      get(){
        return i18nService.getActiveLanguage()
      },
      set(lang){
        i18nService.setActiveLanguage(lang)
      }
    }
  }
};

const i18nService = {
  defaultLanguage: "en",
  languages: [
    {
      lang: "en",
      name: "English",
    },
    {
      lang: "nl",
      name: "Nederlands",
    }
  ],
  setActiveLanguage(lang) {
    localStorage.setItem("language", lang);
  },
  getActiveLanguage() {
    return localStorage.getItem("language") || this.defaultLanguage;
  }
};
</script>
```

---

#### If you need Bootstrap, I would recommend `b-form-select` instead:

And change your language objects to use `value` and `text`

```js
<template>
    <b-form-select v-model="language" :options="languages"></b-form-select>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    languages() {
      return i18nService.languages
    },
    language: {
      get(){
        return i18nService.getActiveLanguage()
      },
      set(lang){
        i18nService.setActiveLanguage(lang)
      }
    }
  }
};

const i18nService = {
  defaultLanguage: "en",
  languages: [
    {
      value: "en",
      text: "English",
    },
    {
      value: "nl",
      text: "Nederlands",
    }
  ],
  setActiveLanguage(lang) {
    localStorage.setItem("language", value);
  },
  getActiveLanguage() {
    return localStorage.getItem("language") || this.defaultLanguage;
  }
};
</script>
```